# Substring of parameter Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate

Would it be possible in hibernate to write a hql query like below.

```
select name from emp where emp.name = SUBSTRING(:NameParam, 0, LENGTH(emp.name)-1)
```

Our database stores only <10 characters. if user enters StephanyBeth in search, database has StephanyBe. I'd like to retrieve the record in the query.

Comment: Why not do the substring before passing the param to the query?

Comment: because I don't know what is the length of the name stored in database.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. If you know the database stores only 0 to 9 characters, just check the length of the variable you receive and if it is bigger than 9, substring it. You don't need to substring every input and you don't need to know the value in the database to know if you should substring or not, after all your substring will always be the same `string.substring(0, 10)`.

Comment: Now your explanation was a LOT clearer than the question. You should update the question with it.